# Cassandra 1.1.10 streaming hangs on rebuild

Tags: cassandra, rebuild, nodetool

I'm doing little experiment with a couple of Cassandra servers. 
The thing is that I want to add a new datacenter to an existing cluster.
Using 1.1.10 version and following this guidelines:
http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/cluster_management

Everything goes well until suddenly the stream stops. Sometimes stops when copying a file and sometimes just stops without errors.

What I do is remove all the data, restart Cassandra and start the rebuild process.
Since the rebuilds doesn't finish, it is a good idea to leave the data that was transferred and execute repairs?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this issue changing the streaming_socket_timeout_in_ms on the yaml file to 30000